# [Cloudbreak][EC2] Enable autoscaling feature

Tags: amazon-web-services, hortonworks-data-platform, autoscaling, cloudbreak

I am trying to setup autoscaling cluster on aws using cloudbreak.

I followed following links to setup cloudbreak, ambari and HDP.

https://hortonworks.github.io/cloudbreak-documentation/latest/aws-launch/index.html
https://hortonworks.github.io/cloudbreak-documentation/latest/aws-create/index.html

I used community cloudbreak image(ami-82324cf8 - US East (N. Virginia)). My cloudbreak version is 2.2.0.

I am using replica of builtin blueprint(Data Science: Apache Spark 2.1, Apache Zeppelin 0.7.0)

Now, my problem is that I can't see autoscaling option in cloudbreak, there is an option of manually resizing my cluster under actions but I can't see any autoscaling option anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that version of Cloudbreak UI does not support auto scaling.

> Try 2.4 or newer.

This exact question was already answered here:
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/174055/cloudbreakec2-enable-autoscaling-feature.html

More detail about feature parity with older versions:
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/158833/auto-scaling-management-interface-in-the-cloudbrea.html